# Add 30 second intervals to UTC string leveraging MomentJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, momentjs

I have a UTC string in "2017-07-11T05:02:36.207465" and I would like to incrementally add 30 seconds at a time for a length less than or equal to say, 1500 (could be any length).

The results of that loop would be stored in an array called, duration.

I would like to leverage [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) to accomplish formatting and adding the 30 second interval.

Here is my preliminary code:

```
var utcstring = "2017-07-11T05:02:36.207465";
var duration = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
    // moment(utcstring).format("h:mm:ss a");
    // moment.add(30, 's');
    // duration.push();
}

console.log(duration); // Should return: ["5:02:36 am", "5:03:06 am", "5:03:36 am", etc.]
```

Your JavaScript and MomentJS knowledge would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply:

- Parse your input string using [`moment.utc`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)
- Add 30 seconds using [`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)
- Use [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to convert moment object to the desired format

Please note that, as stated in the [Mutability](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/mutability/) guide:

> The moment object in Moment.js is mutable. This means that operations like add, subtract, or set change the original moment object.

Here a working sample:

```js
var utcstring = "2017-07-11T05:02:36.207465";
var duration = [];

var m = moment.utc(utcstring);
for (var i = 0; i < 1500; i++) {
  duration.push( m.format("h:mm:ss a") );
  m.add(30, 's');
}

console.log(duration);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```